# C# Question:Dynamically Disable ToolStripMenuItems/ToolStripButtons in an MDIParent Form: Which Event?

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripbutton

Any guidance on the following issue would be greatly appreciated. In which MDIParent event should I disable the items/buttons? Activated? On program Launch, I want the buttons disabled. If there are no active MDIChildren, I want the buttons disabled. When I launch a child form, I want to test that child form for data. If it is a blank form, I want the buttons to remain disabled. I currently have my code in the MdiChildActivated Event Handler. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Activate Event to disable all items/buttons. In the MDIChildActive Event I test for a blank form. If not blank, I enable the items/buttons.

Answer (score -1):

I would use MDI Parent form's MdiChildActivate event:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildactivate.aspx

Please note this remark from that page:

You can use this event to perform tasks such as updating the contents of the MDI child form and *changing* the menu options available in the MDI parent form based on the status of the MDI child form that is activated.

Also note that this event is also called when a child is closed (from MSDN):
Occurs when a multiple-document interface (MDI) child form is activated or *closed* within an MDI application.

That means that in this event you could do something like:

menuButton.Enabled = (this.MdiChildren.Length > 0);

or, if you need to check all child forms for some condition, and if one of children needs enabled button then enable the button:

```
    void Form1_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Form child in MdiChildren)
        {
            if (IsToolbarButtonNeededForThisForm(child))
            {
                toolButton.Enabled = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        toolButton.Enabled = false;
```